# Strange formatting of legend in ggplotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to turn a ggplot into a plotly. The ggplot renders fine, but when I put it through ggplotly, suddenly the legend adds parenthesis and ",1" after the label.

Here's a sample fake data:

```
sorted1<-data.frame(CommDate=c(as.Date("2017-09-12"), as.Date("2017-10-15")), CommName=c("Foo", "Bar"), PubB4=c(2,3))
```

And here's the code I'm trying to run on it:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(sorted1, aes(x=as.Date(CommDate), y=PubB4))+
           geom_smooth(level=0.0, aes(colour="Moving average"), se=FALSE)+
           geom_point(aes(fill=CommName), size=4)+
           expand_limits(y=c(0,4.5))+
           geom_line(mapping=aes(y=4),colour="orangered3",size=1)+
           geom_text(mapping=aes(y=4.2, x=min(sorted1$CommDate)+4), label="Target", size=3)+
           xlab("Committee Date")+
           guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Committee Names"), colour=guide_legend(title.theme=element_blank(),title=NULL))+
           scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"))+
           theme_light()+
           theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=12),panel.grid.major.x = (element_blank()), 
                 panel.grid.minor.x = (element_blank()), 
                 axis.title = element_text(size=8), legend.title = element_text(size=10),
                 legend.text = element_text(size=8), legend.box = 'vertical', legend.spacing.y = unit(-2,"mm"))+
           scale_colour_manual(name="",values="#0072B2"))
```

(the `geom_smooth` doesn't render here, but it does with the full data.)

Here's what I get from this:

[image: ggplotly result with misformatted legend]

Why does the legend show up as "(foo,1)"?

I tried removing the `geom_smooth` which actually solved the problem, but I need it there - how can I keep it but fix the legend?

Thanks!

**Update:** OK, I started commenting out stuff to see what happens. If I remove the `aes()` from the `geom_smooth`, that also fixes the problem, as long as I keep the `scale_colour_manual` commented off as well. But I really would like to have control over the `geom_smooth`'s aesthetics, and include it in the legend. So I'm making progress, but still not quite there...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's yet another elegant solution. Under the hood it detects if a plotly legend name option is available and if so, removes the "(" and ",1)".

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data = data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2017-09-12","2017-10-15")), PubB4=c(2,3), category=c("Foo", "Bar"))

myplot = ggplotly(ggplot(data, aes(x=Date, y=PubB4))+
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept=2.5, color="my line label"))+
    geom_point(aes(fill=category), size=4))

for (i in 1:length(myplot$x$data)){
    if (!is.null(myplot$x$data[[i]]$name)){
        myplot$x$data[[i]]$name =  gsub("\\(","",str_split(myplot$x$data[[i]]$name,",")[[1]][1])
    }
}

myplot
```

[image: plot result]

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that worked for me.  It involves diving into the resulting plotly object and cleaning up the legend names.

The first part creates a function to detect if the plotly list element has a legend specified and then cleans it up.

```
clean_plotly_leg <- function(.plotly_x, .extract_str) {
  # Inpects an x$data list in a plotly object, cleans up legend values where appropriate
  if ("legendgroup" %in% names(.plotly_x)) {
    # The list includes a legend group

    .plotly_x$legendgroup <- stringr::str_extract(.plotly_x$legendgroup, .extract_str)
    .plotly_x$name <- stringr::str_extract(.plotly_x$name, .extract_str)

  }
  .plotly_x


}
```

The second part applies it to your example, but with an intermediate step.

```
sorted_plotly <-
  ggplotly(ggplot(sorted1, aes(x=as.Date(CommDate), y=PubB4))+
           geom_smooth(level=0.0, aes(colour="Moving average"), se=FALSE)+
           geom_point(aes(fill=CommName), size=4)+
           expand_limits(y=c(0,4.5))+
           geom_line(mapping=aes(y=4),colour="orangered3",size=1)+
           geom_text(mapping=aes(y=4.2, x=min(sorted1$CommDate)+4), label="Target", size=3)+
           xlab("Committee Date")+
           guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Committee Names"), colour=guide_legend(title.theme=element_blank(),title=NULL))+
           scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"))+
           theme_light()+
           theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=12),panel.grid.major.x = (element_blank()), 
                 panel.grid.minor.x = (element_blank()), 
                 axis.title = element_text(size=8), legend.title = element_text(size=10),
                 legend.text = element_text(size=8), legend.box = 'vertical', legend.spacing.y = unit(-2,"mm"))+
           scale_colour_manual(name="",values="#0072B2"))

sorted_plotly$x$data <-
  sorted_plotly$x$data %>% 
  map(clean_plotly_leg, "[^\\(][^,]*") # ie remove the opening bracket, if one exists, and extract each character up to the first comma

sorted_plotly
```

I'd welcome any suggestions for making this code more efficient, but at least it works

Answer (score 1):

Since nothing I did worked, I took the dive and taught myself how to create the chart directly in `plotly`. For the benefit of possible future viewers, here's how the chart is recreated in `plotly` (sans some beautification that I'll get around to another time):

```
plot_ly(sorted, x=~CommDate) %>%
  add_markers(y=~PubB4, color=~factor(CommName), size=I(15)) %>% 
  add_lines(x=loess.smooth(sorted$CommDate,sorted$PubB4)$x,         
    y=loess.smooth(sorted$CommDate,sorted$PubB4)$y, name = "Rolling Average", 
    showlegend = TRUE, size=I(3)) %>%
  add_lines(x=c(min(sorted$CommDate),max(sorted$CommDate)),y=4, 
    color=I("red"), name="target", size=I(3)) %>%
  layout(yaxis=(list(range=c(0,max(c(4.5,sorted$PubB4))))),xaxis=list(range=c(min(sorted$CommDate)-10, max(sorted$CommDate)+5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023-10-26 the easiest and cleanest way to address Plotly's known issue of adding parentheses on dummy scales is setting the respective guide/legend to none, using e.g. `guides(color = "none") +`.

[image]

Full reprex:

```
# set to FALSE to use original code
fix_plotly_legend = T

sorted1<-data.frame(CommDate=c(as.Date("2017-09-12"), as.Date("2017-10-15")), CommName=c("Foo", "Bar"), PubB4=c(2,3))
plotly::ggplotly(ggplot(sorted1, aes(x=as.Date(CommDate), y=PubB4))+
                   geom_smooth(level=0.0, aes(colour="Moving average"), se=FALSE)+
                   geom_point(aes(fill=CommName), size=4)+
                   expand_limits(y=c(0,4.5))+
                   geom_line(mapping=aes(y=4),colour="orangered3",size=1)+
                   geom_text(mapping=aes(y=4.2, x=min(sorted1$CommDate)+4), label="Target", size=3)+
                   xlab("Committee Date")+
                   guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Committee Names"), colour=guide_legend(title.theme=element_blank(),title=NULL))+
                   scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format("%b-%y"))+
                   theme_light()+
                   theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=12),panel.grid.major.x = (element_blank()), 
                         panel.grid.minor.x = (element_blank()), 
                         axis.title = element_text(size=8), legend.title = element_text(size=10),
                         legend.text = element_text(size=8), legend.box = 'vertical', legend.spacing.y = unit(-2,"mm"))+
                   scale_colour_manual(name="",values="#0072B2") +
                   {if (fix_plotly_legend) guides(color = "none") else NULL}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that actually works:

```
# First, repeating your code, noting the plot as p1
# --------------------------------------------------
sorted1<-data.frame(CommDate=c(as.Date("2017-09-12"), as.Date("2017-10-15")), CommName=c("Foo", "Bar"), PubB4=c(2,3))
p1 <- ggplotly(ggplot(sorted1, aes(x=as.Date(CommDate), y=PubB4))+
           geom_smooth(level=0.0, aes(colour="Moving average"), se=FALSE)+
           geom_point(aes(fill=CommName), size=4)+
           expand_limits(y=c(0,4.5))+
           geom_line(mapping=aes(y=4),colour="orangered3",size=1)+
           geom_text(mapping=aes(y=4.2, x=min(sorted1$CommDate)+4), label="Target", size=3)+
           xlab("Committee Date")+
           guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Committee Names"), colour=guide_legend(title.theme=element_blank(),title=NULL))+
           scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b-%y"))+
           theme_light()+
           theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5, size=12),panel.grid.major.x = (element_blank()), 
                 panel.grid.minor.x = (element_blank()), 
                 axis.title = element_text(size=8), legend.title = element_text(size=10),
                 legend.text = element_text(size=8), legend.box = 'vertical', legend.spacing.y = unit(-2,"mm"))+
           scale_colour_manual(name="",values="#0072B2"))
```

Now we can proceed to the workaround:

```
# Now, the workaround:
# ------------------------------------------------------
p1Names <- unique(sorted1$CommName) # we need to know the "true" legend values
for (i in 1:length(p1$x$data)) { # this goes over all places where legend values are stored
  n1 <- p1$x$data[[i]]$name # and this is how the value is stored in plotly
  n2 <- " "
  for (j in 1:length(p1Names)) {
    if (grepl(x = n1, pattern = p1Names[j])) {n2 = p1Names[j]} # if the plotly legend name contains the original value, replace it with the original value
  }
  p1$x$data[[i]]$name <- n2 # now is the time for actual replacement
  if (n2 == " ") {p1$x$data[[i]]$showlegend = FALSE}  # sometimes plotly adds to the legend values that we don't want, this is how to get rid of them, too
}
p1   # now we can see the result :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is out there still having this problem: check that you aren't setting `scale_fill_viridis_d` or something similar, with `fill` when you should be using `scale_color_viridis_d` (i.e. check you `aes()` to see if you are using `color` of `fill` or both).

Another check to make is if the dataset is grouped or not, if it is grouped, you should `ungroup()` before doing the graph