# Aes in ggplotly

Tags: r, shiny, ggplotly

ggplotly prints some stuff from aes, namely "alpha" and "Continent", I have no idea why it goes like this.. please help to remove it!

Look at the upper right corner ->

[image: My shiny app page]

part of the code with ggplot:

```
server <- function(input, output) {    
  observe({
    output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
      p <- ggplot(df1(), aes(x = df1()[,4], y = Happiness.Score))
      p <- p + geom_point(size = 2, aes(text = paste("Country:", df1()[,1]), color = Continent,  alpha = 0.85)) + 
        labs(title = "How happy is the country?", x = names(df1())[4], y = "Happiness Score") + 
        theme_light(base_size = 12) + ylim(2,8) 
      ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("text", "y"))
    })
  })
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133395/strange-formatting-of-legend-in-ggplotly-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Continent` is the legend title. To change it, you can do:

```
...... + scale_color_discrete(name = "MY_LEGEND_TITLE")
```

To get rid of the `alpha`, set it outside the `aes`:

```
geom_point(aes(text = paste("Country:", df1()[,1]), color = Continent), 
           size = 2, alpha = 0.85)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's helped!