# Number on the right in an R chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I'm trying to represent a graph in R but when I paint it I get a ,1 next to high, low and normal, like this: (High,1) Is it possible to eliminate the apparentis and the ,1 so that only High, Low and Normal are shown?

Code:

```
output$grafica <-renderPlotly({
   p <- ggplot(data(), aes(x=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[15]]),
                           fill=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[5]])) + 
     geom_bar(stat="count") +
     scale_fill_manual(values=c("#810f7c", "#8856a7", "#8c96c6"))+
     theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
     scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
     labs(title="Number", 
          y="Issues", 
          x="Project",
          fill= "Priority")
 })
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: This might solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133395/strange-formatting-of-legend-in-ggplotly-in-r

Answer (score 0):

add

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#810f7c", "#8856a7", "#8c96c6"),
labels=c("High", "Low", "Normal"))
```

to your scale_fill_manual()

Comment: I obtain the same :(

Comment: what about: + scale_shape_discrete(name  ="Priority",
                           breaks=c("High", "Low", "Normal"),
                           labels=c("High", "Low", "Normal"))

Comment: Now, a "NA" appears

Answer (score 0):

i obtain the same with this code :

```
output$grafica4 <-renderPlotly({
   p <- ggplot(data(), aes(x=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[15]]),
                           fill=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[5]]))) + 
     geom_bar(stat="count") +
     scale_fill_manual(labels=c("High", "Low", "Normal"), 
                       values=c("#810f7c", "#8856a7","#8c96c6"),
                       name="Priority")+
     theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
     scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
     labs(title="Number", 
          y="Issues", 
          x="Project")
 })
```

[image]

Comment: what if you added the legend names under scale_colour_manual(name="Priority",values=c("High", "Low", "Normal"))

Comment: same as my first comment (without NA but with ,1)

Answer (score 0):

New code :

```
 output$grafica4 <-renderPlotly({
   p <- ggplot(data(), aes(x=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[15]]),
                           fill=as.factor(data()[,names(data())[5]]))) + 
     geom_bar(stat="count") +
     #scale_fill_manual(labels=c("High", "Low", "Normal"), 
      #                 values=c("#810f7c", "#8856a7","#8c96c6"),
       #                name="Priority")+
     scale_shape_discrete(name ="Priority", breaks=c("High", "Low", "Normal"), 
                          labels=c("High", "Low", "Normal"))+
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1))+
     scale_color_viridis(discrete = TRUE) + 
     labs(title="Number", 
          y="Issues", 
          x="Project",
          fill="Priority")
 })
```

[image]