# Remove parenthesis from ggplotly legend

Tags: r

I found [this example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133395/strange-formatting-of-legend-in-ggplotly-in-r) which provides a perfect way of getting rid of the extra terms added by ggplotly to the legends.

My problem is that the code in the solution removes everything after a comma `,` and I have an actual comma is my legends which are in the format of `DIC, Spliced`

The code is:

```
for (i in 1:length(myplot$x$data)){
    if (!is.null(myplot$x$data[[i]]$name)){
        myplot$x$data[[i]]$name =  gsub("\\(","",str_split(myplot$x$data[[i]]$name,",")[[1]][1])
    }
}
```

My original plot has this kind of legend:

[image]

After applying the code, I loose my `Spliced/Uspliced` terms in my legends

[image]

Comment: Can you show your actual data and plot? Forget about that other answer, it’s quite a wonky approach that shouldn’t be necessary to generate proper legends.

Answer (score 3):

So `plotly` always turns the new legend to be `(orignal_legend,1)`(Weird). Is it always `,1)` ?  or can be `,2)` or any other number. I don't know.

If your original legend is `(DIC, Spliced, 1)` it will become `((DIC, Spliced, 1), 1)` with `plotly`. So you have to remove the beginning round brackets and ending `,1)` from the legend. Try this regex with `gsub` :

```
for (i in 1:length(myplot$x$data)){
  if (!is.null(myplot$x$data[[i]]$name)){
    myplot$x$data[[i]]$name = gsub('^\\(|,\\d+\\)$', '', myplot$x$data[[i]]$name)
  }
}
```

As mentioned earlier I am not sure if it is going to be always `,1)` or can be `,2)` as well, so to be on the safer side I have used `\\d+` which will remove any number at the end of the string.

Comment: ‘plotly’ doesn’t *generally* do this, no. It does that when the legend combines multiple aesthetics, and the the legend title then is a comma-separated list of these aesthetics. E.g. `(‹color›, ‹fill›)`.