# keep two legends from ggplot plot using plotly::ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

When I convert a `ggplot` with two separate legends to `plotly` (using `ggplotly`), the two legends merge. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(date = 
                   as.Date(c("01/01/1998", "10/01/1998", "15/01/1998", 
                             "25/01/1998", "01/02/1998", "12/02/1998", "20/02/1998"), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 date2 = as.Date(c(NA, "10/01/1998", NA, 
                                   NA, NA, NA, NA), "%d/%m/%Y"),
                 counts = c(12, 10, 2, 24, 15, 1, 14),
                 yes_no = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "no", "no", "no", "no"))
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = counts)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = counts, fill = yes_no), color = NA, alpha = 0.5) +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(name = "status 1", palette = "Accent") +
  geom_vline(mapping = aes(xintercept = as.numeric(date2), col = "mystatistic")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "statistics", values = c("mystatistic" = "red")) 
gg
```

which produces two legends:

[image]

but when I convert to `plotly`:

```
ggplotly(gg)
```

it returns one legend with second legend title missing:

[image]

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49133395/strange-formatting-of-legend-in-ggplotly-in-r) is useful to remove the parenthesis and comma from the current plot but that's not the fix I am looking for.

thanks